# MIPS how to read a line of integers from keyboard?

Tags: mips

I want to read a line of integers from the keyboard in mips and store it in a register. However doing something like this only reads 1 int.

```
 li $v0, 5
 syscall
```

I want to store a whole word, like this: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 as an array in the register. How can I do this?

Comment: Read string. Parse string.